# In Ios, download stops on locking of device. Is there any way the download continues in background?

Tags: ios, react-native

In ios, When we lock the screen the device goes into sleep mode and stops the download process and disrupts it. I used the react-native-keep-awake dependency but locks the screen anyway and is not a permanent solution. Is there any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Check out https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/app_and_environment/scenes/preparing_your_ui_to_run_in_the_background/updating_your_app_with_background_app_refresh.

However, in the end you only have a short period of time to download data.

Comment: We are downloading large chunk of data which is around 1.5GB.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/url_loading_system/downloading_files_in_the_background

Comment: Is there any solution with respect to react-native. Like a library which would help with this?